# Why is domain limited to all real numbers?

Tags: functions

In my math class, we were going over how to find the domain of functions (pretty basic stuff). One of the problems, however, made me a bit confused.

The equasion was: 1/x^(2) + 3
or something similar. The teacher explained how the domain was the set of all real numbers (since even exponents always give positive answers), but if you plug in i, wont you get a ‘real’ answer since i^(2) is -1? or is the complex plane totally different in this context?

Comment: More likely it was $\frac{1}{x^2+3}$ not $\frac{1}{x^2}+3$ (*which is what one would assume you meant looking at what you have written*).  Often times in introductory pre-calculus classes you are tasked with finding the maximal subset of $\Bbb R$ for which the function is well defined.

Comment: [Questions of the type "find the domain" are not well-defined anyway](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26957/328173), so just follow the rules for this one.

Comment: These kinds of 'find the domain' questions typically assume that you start with the reals and then throw out what doesn't work ... don't ask me why ... as Kenny says, just play the game

Comment: $i^2=-1$ not +$1$

Comment: Also, as an aside., even exponents always give *non-negative* answers (*for real inputs*).  There is a distinction between "non-negative" and "strictly positive" in that zero is a possible output.  Further, $i^2=-1$, not $1$ and plugging in $i$ to this will actually give a real output.  If you were to plug in something else though, like $1+i$ you will find that you get a non-real output.

Comment: Yes, i^2 is -1 not 1 idk what I was thinking. And also, (1/(x^(2) + 3)) is what I meant, not ((1/(x^(2)) + 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most precalculus and calculus questions, it's assumed that the universal background set is $\Bbb{R}$, the real numbers. If you decide to work in a complex context, and consider the same function there, it would be appropriate to say that its largest possible domain of definition is $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{\pm\sqrt3 i\}$.

Unless there's a reason to think we're in a context where functions are viewed as being defined on subsets of $\Bbb{C}$ as opposed to subsets of $\Bbb{R}$, the usual answer would be that the domain is $\Bbb{R}$, because $f(x)$ is defined for all real numbers.

It is often conventional, if we want to think about the complex case, to indicate this by calling the independent variable $z$ instead of $x$, so if you write $f(z) = \frac1{z^2+3}$, many people will assume you're talking about a function on $\Bbb{C}$, which is undefined at two points in the plane.